# How does "gaining the right" to advance classes work?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

As I mentioned in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/309379/162442), class changes are done at Shrines of Mila, rather than via Seals, so I'm at a loss for the way class changes work in this game.

That said, I've noticed some disparity in the way units have been "gaining the right" to advance classes. For instance, Lukas gained the right to the Knight class once he hit level 7 as a Soldier, similar to the way Tobin gained the right to the Myrmidon class at level 7 as a Mercenary. However, Alm has yet to gain the right to advance past the Fighter class (it is the the same "level" as the Soldier and Mercenary classes), despite being level 8. Faye also has yet to gain the right to a class higher than Pegasus Knight (she's level 8, as well).

Is there some sort of criteria for gaining the right to different classes? If I choose not to change classes right away, will I eventually get more options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing more and eventually looking it up, I discovered that different classes simply unlock the next tier at different levels. From [this guide](http://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5564-fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-of-valentia-guide-when-to-promote-characters-for-their-class-change-villager-promotion):

> Here is the breakdown for when each character class can be promoted at their earliest:
>
> - Mercenary promotes to Myrmidon **(Level 7)**, who then promotes to Dread Fighter **(Level 10)**
> - Soldier promotes to Knight **(Level 7)**, who then promotes to Baron **(Level 10)**
> - Archer promotes to Sniper **(Level 7)**, who then promotes to Bow Knight **(Level 10)**
> - Cavalier promotes to Paladin **(Level 7)**, who when promotes to Gold Knight **(Level 10)**
> - Pegasus Knight promotes to Falcon Knight **(Level 12)**
> - Cleric promotes to Saint **(Level 12)**
> - Male Mage promotes to Sage **(Level 12)**
> - Female Mage promotes to Priestess **(Level 14)**